# Oracle update based on a value from another table

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I have two tables ROOMS and LEASE as described below

```
create table ROOMS (ROOM_NUM number, FLOOR varchar2(50))
create table LEASE (ROOM_NUM number, RENT_RATE number(4,2))
```

I want to set the rent_rate in the LEASE table to 3.50 for all rooms that have FLOOR='Carpet' in the ROOMS table.

I have looked at MANY examples but cannot seem to come up with a solution.

I realize that I didn't make ROOM_NUM primary or foreign keys but I am just using 3 records for a test problem and have ensured that they room numbers exist in both tables

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE LEASE
SET RENT_RATE = 3.5
WHERE ROOM_NUM IN (SELECT ROOM_NUM FROM ROOMS WHERE FLOOR='Carpet')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update lease
   set rent_rate = 3.50
where room_num in(select room_num from rooms where FLOOR='Carpet');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

And, if you need to create the rows rather than updating existing rows:

```
INSERT INTO LEASE
(SELECT ROOM_NUM, 3.5 FROM ROOMS WHERE FLOOR = 'Carpet');
```